# Class 'mysqli' not found

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I understand that this question is asked multiple times here but my scenario is a bit different because I have compiled php5.

I configured php with `--with-mysqli=mysqlnd` option and the output of the command :

```
 cat php.ini | grep extension
```

gave me below results.

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/"
extension=imap.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysqlnd.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Also, the the listing of the files using

```
sudo ls -l /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/
```

gave me below results.

```
total 1312
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 302845 Mar 14 19:20 imap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 127672 Mar 15 00:08 mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 196760 Mar 15 00:08 mysqlnd.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47168 Mar 15 00:08 mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 522240 Mar 14 12:57 opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  26960 Mar 15 00:09 pdo_mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 104808 Mar 15 00:09 pdo.so
```

Having this configuration, I still ran into the following error:

```
 [Sat Mar 14 23:49:37.520219 2015] [:error] [pid 8142:tid   
 140418847074048] [client 127.0.0.1:34142] PHP Fatal error: Class   
 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/warmmail/db_fns.php on line 5
```

Now to test if mysqli is loaded I put the following code in one of my
landing pages :

```
<?php
echo 'Loaded .ini file is : '.php_ini_loaded_file();
echo '<br /><br />Function sets supported in this install are:<br />';
$extensions = get_loaded_extensions();
foreach($extensions as $each_ext)
{
echo "$each_ext<br />";
echo '<ul>';
$ext_funcs=get_extension_funcs($each_ext);
foreach($ext_funcs as $func)
{
echo "<li>$func</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

and I got the below output (only excerpts shown as it is a big list)

```
          o
          o
          o
    posix_get_last_error
    posix_errno
    posix_strerror
    posix_initgroups

Reflection

mysqlnd

shmop

    shmop_open
    shmop_read
    shmop_close
    shmop_size
    shmop_write
    shmop_delete
          o
          o
          o
```

As we can see the mysql native driver(mysqlnd) is loaded but the mysqli extension and its functions(**which I am looking for)**is not loaded.

**Edit 1**

```
   php -i | grep -n mysqli
```

gave the below result.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mysqli.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: core_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mysqlnd.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/mysqlnd.so: undefined symbol: core_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: core_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

What should I do get the mysqli up and running?

Comment: Instead of looking in code to determine loaded extensions, on the CLI you can list them with `php -m` (though it may load a different php.ini than the web server). Look also at the output from `php -i` or the `phpinfo()` function in your script for formatted output.

Comment: Since you compiled PHP, I'll assume you restarted the web server afterward to load the new PHP...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yes I restarted apache & php -m do list mysql
mysqlnd but no mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure it out myself.
Initially my configure script was :

```
sudo ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs 
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config --with-pdo-mysql=/usr 
/bin/mysql_config --enable-embedded_mysqli --enable-embedded-
pdo-mysql --with-zlib --with-gd --with-mhash --with-mcrypt
--with-curl --with-openssl --with-zlib --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir    
--with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --enable-calendar --enable-exif 
--enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-
sockets --enable-wddx --enable-zip
```

**mysql_config** in the **/usr/bin/** was added by the **libmysqlclient-dev**
Debian package and not my compiled mysql. In fact the **mysql_config** file from my compiled mysql was found in the folder **/usr/local/mysql/bin/**.

So I changed my configure script as below and recompiled php :

```
 sudo ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs 
 --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql
 /bin/mysql_config --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
 --enable-embedded_mysqli --enable-embedded-pdo-mysql --with-zlib 
 --with-gd --with-mhash --with-mcrypt --with-curl --with-openssl 
 --with-zlib --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-pcre-regex --enable- 
 calendar --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-mbstring --enable-shmop  
 --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-wddx --enable-zip
```

This solved the issue.